# Issue with AndroidX with flutter plug In "rmtmckenzie/flutter_qr_mobile_vision"

Tags: flutter, androidx

I have a problem compiling the newest version with a new flutter project that was set up for AndroidX

these are the errors I am getting:

> /Users/tarzon/Documents/Flutter_SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_mobile_vision-0.2.2/android/src/main/java/com/github/rmtmckenzie/qrmobilevision/QrCameraC2.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
>   import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
>                             ^
>     symbol:   class NonNull
>     location: package androidx.annotation
>   /Users/tarzon/Documents/Flutter_SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_mobile_vision-0.2.2/android/src/main/java/com/github/rmtmckenzie/qrmobilevision/QrMobileVisionPlugin.java:6: error: package androidx.core.app does not exist
>   import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
>                           ^
>   /Users/tarzon/Documents/Flutter_SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_mobile_vision-0.2.2/android/src/main/java/com/github/rmtmckenzie/qrmobilevision/QrCameraC2.java:127: error: cannot find symbol
>                   public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice device) {
>                                         ^
>     symbol: class NonNull
>   /Users/tarzon/Documents/Flutter_SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_mobile_vision-0.2.2/android/src/main/java/com/github/rmtmckenzie/qrmobilevision/QrCameraC2.java:133: error: cannot find symbol
>                   public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice device) {
>                                               ^
>     symbol: class NonNull
>   /Users/tarzon/Documents/Flutter_SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_mobile_vision-0.2.2/android/src/main/java/com/github/rmtmckenzie/qrmobilevision/QrCameraC2.java:137: error: cannot find symbol
>                   public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice device, int error) {
>                                        ^
>     symbol: class NonNull
>   /Users/tarzon/Documents/Flutter_SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_mobile_vision-0.2.2/android/src/main/java/com/github/rmtmckenzie/qrmobilevision/QrCameraC2.java:223: error: cannot find symbol
>                   public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
>                                             ^
>     symbol: class NonNull
>   /Users/tarzon/Documents/Flutter_SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_mobile_vision-0.2.2/android/src/main/java/com/github/rmtmckenzie/qrmobilevision/QrCameraC2.java:229: error: cannot find symbol
>                   public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
>                                                  ^
>     symbol: class NonNull
>   /Users/tarzon/Documents/Flutter_SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_mobile_vision-0.2.2/android/src/main/java/com/github/rmtmckenzie/qrmobilevision/QrCameraC2.java:242: error: cannot find symbol
>               public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
>                                               ^
>     symbol: class NonNull
>   /Users/tarzon/Documents/Flutter_SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_mobile_vision-0.2.2/android/src/main/java/com/github/rmtmckenzie/qrmobilevision/QrCameraC2.java:242: error: cannot find symbol
>               public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
>                                                                                      ^
>     symbol: class NonNull
>   /Users/tarzon/Documents/Flutter_SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_mobile_vision-0.2.2/android/src/main/java/com/github/rmtmckenzie/qrmobilevision/QrCameraC2.java:242: error: cannot find symbol
>               public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
>                                                                                                                       ^
>     symbol: class NonNull
>   /Users/tarzon/Documents/Flutter_SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_mobile_vision-0.2.2/android/src/main/java/com/github/rmtmckenzie/qrmobilevision/QrMobileVisionPlugin.java:118: error: cannot find symbol
>                           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context,
>                           ^
>     symbol:   variable ActivityCompat
>     location: class QrMobileVisionPlugin
>   Note: /Users/tarzon/Documents/Flutter_SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_mobile_vision-0.2.2/android/src/main/java/com/github/rmtmckenzie/qrmobilevision/QrCameraC1.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   11 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':qr_mobile_vision:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

---

The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.

---

Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

***Here is my build.gradle file in side flutter android package***

```
enter def flutterPluginVersion = 'managed'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 28

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
    targetCompatibility 1.8
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mpos_flutter.host"
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    profile {
        initWith debug
    }
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}

buildDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "../build/host")

dependencies {
implementation project(':flutter')
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0-rc01'
dependencies {
implementation project(':flutter')
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0-rc01'

}
```

Comment: Can you please share the list of dependencies from your build.gradle file?

Comment: @Ovidiu Here is my android's build file in side flutter project. Please check updated question .

Comment: Are you meant to have a Flutter module within a native Android app? Your question mentions 'a new Flutter project', which wouldn't imply a dependency on the 'flutter' project, would not be compatible with Espresso, and would not require any of the support libraries.

Comment: @Ovidiu Look I have an android project which is in androidx, now I want make some functionalities in flutter so make a flutter module and link with android project but my main project is Android One.     
Now i want to use “rmtmckenzie/flutter_qr_mobile_vision” scanner plugin in flutter module but it giving me above  issue.

Comment: @Ovidiu Can you please check if you want I can share some code.